# Does "end up" have a negative connotation?

Tags: connotation, phrasal-verbs

Maybe not, as some of the example usages in [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/end-up), but it still has a negative feel to me. Is there some positive way that can be used instead?

Comment: Delete or close General Reference. Question answers itself in reference cited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't have negative connotations in itself.

> Abraham Lincoln was born in Kentucky, and ended up the 16th president of the United States.

There are no negative connotations there.

> If you keep that up, you'll end up in jail.

Here, there are no negative connotations from "end up" either. If we replaced "jail" with "the  White House", it would be a positive sentence. "End up" has no bearing on the positive or negative connotations of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder though what is a more common usage/connotation?

Comment: "End up" is very common.

Comment: Yes, but is it more used more common negatively or positively?

Comment: I really couldn't say. Between positive and negative, it's split fifty-fifty. It isn't really associated with positive or negative.

Comment: I agree that end up doesn't necessarily have a negative connotation. However, the core component of end up is "did not intend/plan/want". In some contexts, lack of planning implies negativity.

Comment: I agree with Luke that "lack of planning" is not part of the connotaiton of this phrase.