# Is it rude to say "how did you end up here"?

Tags: politeness, phrasing

Is it rude to say, "how did you end up here?" to a teacher?

I said it to my English teacher, and then thought, "damn, I don't know if I'm supposed to phrase it that way or not."

So, is it?

Comment: It probably depends a lot on the *way* you asked the question. It does kind of sound like you implied "in a dead-end, thankless job like this," but if you were sincerely asking how he or she became a teacher so that you might one day become one, then it was perhaps fine.

Comment: "So what brought you here?" might help avoid the implication @JLG describes.

Comment: Do you mean being a teacher in general, or at this particular school?  "What made you decide to become a teacher?" might be good for the former and "How did you decide to come teach at <your school name here>?" for the latter.

Comment: Does your English teacher know that you use a lower-case "i" when you should use an upper case one, and you don't start quotes with capital letters? If so, maybe the teacher is wondering the same thing.

Comment: @J.R. presumably NewProger is taking English classes because he or she is school-aged or a non-native speaker. Take it easy.

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. There's nothing inherently positive or negative about *ending up* anywhere, as can easily be seen by scanning through the various ways ["How did you end up becoming"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22how+did+you+end+up+becoming%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is completed.

Comment: Relevant to the point of being a duplicate: [Does "end up" have a negative connotation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80521/does-end-up-have-a-negative-connotation)

Comment: I agree with Andrew - duplicate (I didn't vote Not Constructive)

Comment: @Ryan: I was chiding, but I meant it to be light-hearted. (Nowadays, using lower-case "i" instead of "I" is often a clue that someone is using their phone instead of their keyboard; if betting on the root cause; that's where I would've placed my bet.) I felt it would be good to make mention of it, but, like you, I didn't see a need to be overly harsh. I hope I didn't come across that way.

Comment: @J.R., I may have been overly sensitive - I can see your reading too. You're right about the lower case. It's sooo hard to tell online, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *end up* can have a neutral [meaning](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/end-up)

> to become eventually; turn out to be *he ended up a thief*
>
> to arrive, esp by a circuitous or lengthy route or process: *he ended up living in New Zealand*

However, as shown from most of the examples, it commonly has a slightly pejorative connotation

> to be in a particular place or state after doing something or because of doing it: *Keep on doing that and you'll end up in serious trouble.*
>
> *Somehow they all ended up at my house.*
>
> end up doing something: *I ended up spending the night in the airport.*

Because of that connotation, without more context, it may seem rude to many listeners.